# scheme - function "if"

Tags: scheme

In the next code

```
(if (exp1)
    (Do1)
    (Do2))
```

(Do1) is happening when exp1 is true. My problem that I want to do **two** things if the condition is true. meaning - I want to add a link to list, and also call the function again.

```
so Do1 in my program is:
           ((cons (car hello) list1)
            (Myfunction (cdr data) list1))
```

and It give me the next problem:

```
procedure application: expected procedure, given: ((439043 Mylist)); arguments were: ()
```

How can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `(begin)` to put a bunch of statements into one combination. **However, I don't think that's what you want here.** What is the effect of `(cons (car hello) list1)`? Nothing. `(cons)` *returns* a list, it doesn't alter any of its arguments.

So in fact, I think you want `do1` to be `(Myfunction (cdr data) (cons (car hello) list1))`

That's just a single statement and can go in the consequent of your `(if)` without using a `(begin)`.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! It works (the begin doesnt help in run time)

Comment: The reason the `begin` didn't help is that the `cons` is doing nothing in that version. Only functions that end with a ! (like `set!`) alter their arguments in Scheme.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `begin` - for example:

```
(begin
       (cons (car hello) list1)
       (Myfunction (cdr data) list1))
```

Comment: While syntactically this is the right answer, drysdam does bring up a good point - are you sure you do not need the result of the (cons)?